# How to block incoming IPv6 fragments?

Tags: firewall, ipv6, fragmentation

I have an issue with my firewall configuration.
I would like to block all IPv6 fragmented packets in a sopecific interface. So, I tried:

```
# ip6tables -A INPUT -d <ipv6_address> -i eth0 -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j DROP
```

But IPv6 fragmented traffic keeps going in.

I have also found this link: https://www.secfu.net/2015/03/25/how-to-block-incoming-ipv6-fragments-in-latest-red-hat-releases/
that explains that ipv6-frag or frag do not block the ipv6 fragmented traffic in the latest CentOS, because after bug id 1011214 (kernel-2.6.32-437.el6) netfilter started processing the reassembled packet instead of the fragments, like IPv4 does. The same article suggests to use nftables which would look like as follows:

```
table ip6 filter {
   chain preroute500 {
      type filter hook prerouting priority -500; policy accept;
      ip6 nexthdr ipv6-frag counter packets 2 bytes 2104
   }
 }
```

How can I do something like that using ip6tables?

```
# cat /etc/system-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

# uname -r
5.0.8-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
```

Comment: You can't do it in ip6tables, as the document you linked to explained. Why do you want to do this at all? Perhaps there is some alternate way to accomplish [your real goal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912).

Comment: My real goal is to test the firewall rule with protocol ipv6-frag|frag|44 protocol. I have created with scapy some fragmented IPv6 packets, however no matter which rule I add, they are not dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said, you should be sure that blocking fragments is really your goal, and not a method you think is best for your goal, while better methods would exist. Anyway, for what it's worth you must:

- use a recent enough kernel. The [feature](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6table_raw.c?h=v4.16-rc1#n16/ip6table_raw.c#L16) was [added in kernel 4.16](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6table_raw.c?h=v4.16-rc1&id=902d6a4c2a4f411582689e53fb101895ffe99028). CentOS uses 3.10. While many features are backported (starting with nftables which isn't available on a vanilla 3.10 kernel but is on RHEL/CentOS's 3.10), this feature wasn't backported as of [latest CentOS 7.6's kernel](http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/updates/Source/SPackages/kernel-3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.src.rpm). Since you're using an "elrepo" 5.0.8 kernel, the feature is present. Here's the feature description and why it exists (mostly for routing, or at least non-stateful/non-NAT firewall routing situations):

  > netfilter: nf_defrag:
  >
  > Skip defrag if NOTRACK is set conntrack defrag
  >   is needed only if some module like CONNTRACK or NAT explicitly
  >   requests it. For plain forwarding scenarios, defrag is not needed and
  >   can be skipped if NOTRACK is set in a rule.
  >
  > Since conntrack defrag is currently higher priority than raw table,
  >   setting NOTRACK is not sufficient. We need to move raw to a higher
  >   priority for iptables only.
  >
  > This is achieved by introducing a module parameter "raw_before_defrag"
  >   which allows to change the priority of raw table to place it before
  >   defrag. By default, the parameter is disabled and the priority of raw
  >   table is NF_IP_PRI_RAW to support legacy behavior. If the module
  >   parameter is enabled, then the priority of the raw table is set to
  >   NF_IP_PRI_RAW_BEFORE_DEFRAG.
- (if needed remove existing raw ip6tables rules, unload and) load the `ip6table_raw` module with the parameter `raw_before_defrag=1`, so the raw's hook (in PREROUTING) switchs from prio -300 to -450, before defrag's -400.

  ```
  modprobe ip6table_raw raw_before_defrag=1
  ```

  which should get a kernel message like `ip6table_raw: Enabling raw table before defrag`

Now  in the `raw` table, and probably making sense only in `PREROUTING`, *ip6tables* will be able to see fragments. It can filter them there, or choose to skip conntrack (`iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING ... -j CT --notrack`), which as explained in the feature patch, will skip defragmentation too, allowing other chains to handle them (of course not including `nat` table's chains nor any other conntrack related feature).

---

Note that to witness the [problem described](https://www.secfu.net/2015/03/25/how-to-block-incoming-ipv6-fragments-in-latest-red-hat-releases/) in a test network namespace, one must first artificially enable *conntrack* operations for *conntrack*'s dependency with *defrag*, which isn't activated until first needed. Here's a network namespace example:

```
ip netns add sender
ip netns add receiver
ip -n sender   link add veth0 address 02:00:00:00:00:01 type veth peer netns receiver name veth0 address 02:00:00:00:00:02
ip -n sender   link set veth0 up
ip -n receiver link set veth0 up
```

This works:

```
# ip netns exec sender ping6 -s 4000 fe80::ff:fe00:2%veth0
PING fe80::ff:fe00:2%veth0(fe80::ff:fe00:2%veth0) 4000 data bytes
4008 bytes from fe80::ff:fe00:2%veth0: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.069 ms
^C
```

After this, it won't work anymore:

```
ip netns exec receiver ip6tables -A INPUT -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j DROP
```

Once *conntrack* is activated in the network namespace with those commands apparently resulting in a no-op:

```
ip netns exec receiver ip6tables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED
ip netns exec receiver ip6tables -D INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

the ipv6 defragmentation is also activated. Now the previous ping will always work, because the rule in INPUT only sees defragmented packets.

With the previously (re)loaded `ip6table_raw` module with parameter `raw_before_defrag=1`, this will restore fragmented ping's blocking:

```
ip netns exec receiver ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j DROP
```

Alternatively, interesting packets can be marked as *notrack*, thus exempting them of *conntrack*, thus not receiving *defrag* treatement either, allowing them to be filtered again with the rule in the `filter/INPUT` chain. So instead of the previous `raw` rule, this would also block the ping packets (3 of them per ping), but this time again in the `filter/INPUT` chain:

```
ip netns exec receiver ip6tables -t raw -A PREROUTING -m ipv6header --header ipv6-frag --soft -j CT --notrack
```

This is an example only which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: added that a packet, including fragments, can also be marked as *notrack* for further (non stateful) processing after the raw table.